# Strange combo switch wiring?

Tags: electrical

I replaced my old sprinkler controller with a new wifi "smart" one. About a day later, I started hearing a buzzing sound from the outlet (only the sprinkler controller was plugged into this outlet). This is in my garage.

The outlet box has a combo switch/outlet: the switch turns power on/off to outlets 2&3 (nothing is connected to these outlets), and outlet 1 had the controller.

A few things seemed wrong right away:

1. More than one wire under the outlet screw
2. The switch breaks neutral wire instead of hot
3. Wrong polarity for receptacle 1 (???) (I
   confirmed red wire is the hot wire).

Not an electrician, but this seems sloppy, which is surprising since the rest of the electrical work in the house seems sound (as far as I can tell doing minor fixes).

Am I missing something obvious here?

My plan is to put in a new combo switch and fix the issues above. Would anything else be needed to be up to code?

[image: Photo-1]

[image: Photo 2]

[image: Schematic]

Comment: I take it you normally have a [domed cover](https://www.homedepot.com/p/4-in-Square-Box-Cover-Single-Duplex-RS12-10R/202591757) there?

Comment: I don’t. The switch/outlet unit looks like it protrudes but it sits flush when the cover is on.

Answer (score 0):

#1 is a maybe, depends on the quality of the switch/outlet.

#2 is bad, only outlets should have neutral connected, not switches(smart switches are exception).

#3 is not good, but easy fix.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, 2&3 makes no sense to me why they’d do this.